# Draw circle cursor in jquery knob

Tags: jquery, canvas, jquery-knob

I want to do something like this image but I don't know how. Please help me and show me the path to draw circle cursor in knob plugin.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**jQuery roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin for this requirement. So you can customize the appearance and functionalities based on your requirement.

Here is the demo same as your requirement: [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/fe7j3ohv/37/)

**Screenshot:**

[image: time selection with round slider]

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

.

**[ Updated the codes ]**

```js
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    handleShape: "round",
    width: 8,
    radius: "80",
    handleSize: "+10",
    startAngle: 270,
    editableTooltip: false,
    min: 1,
    max: 12,
    
    tooltipFormat: function(args) {
      return args.value + " Hour";   
    }
});
$("#slider").roundSlider({ value: 4 });
```

```css
.rs-control .rs-range-color {
    background-color: #ff9700;
}
.rs-control .rs-path-color {
    background-color: #5b4b28;
}
.rs-control .rs-handle {
    background-color: #7dc98f;
}
.rs-border {
    border-width: 0;
}
.rs-tooltip-text {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #5B4B28;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Very good answer, but don't forget to post the code you used. This is useful in case any of the websites you refer to go down. Copy-pasting the JS code into your post here on SO should be enough to give OP an idea.

Comment: It's look exact what i want but that plugin doesn't fullfill my requirement i need a input field in timer too so that user can write instead of fill that circle like jquery-knob do so there is any way thing can be done using knob plugin or u can recommend a plugin that feature is same as jquery-knob

Comment: need input field means what you meant ? are you need the editable input box in the center place ah ?  
like this demo http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/fe7j3ohv/38/

Comment: yup something like that. Thank u